# Django Form validation overview (quick!)

Tags: python, django, validation, frameworks, django-forms

There is reasonably precise
documentation about [Django Form validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/validation/)
and I have used it successfully already,
so what is my problem?

**My problem is remembering this stuff.**

The framework involves redundancy, irregularity, some non-obvious names,
and of course a lot of behind-the-scenes magic
and I do not seem to be able to keep it in my head.

Can somebody help with a description that is
**faster to scan than the original documentation**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assume you have a [Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/) class `MyForm` with an instance called `myform`
and containing various [Fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/), in particular a 
`SomeField` field called `somefield` which we use as an example to understand
what is going on.
`SomeField` can be from Django or your own code.

## The `Form` validation process

These are the validation steps that Django is going to
perform or attempt:

1. `SomeField.to_python(self, value)`

   - called for: each Field of `myform`
   - meaning: converts the string `value` to its Python target type (e.g. `int`)
   - takes input from: `value`
   - returns: `value` coerced into the proper Python type for `SomeField`
   - side effects: should have none
   - signals problems by: raise `ValidationError`
2. `SomeField.validate(self, value)`

   - called for: each Field of `myform`
   - meaning: validates Field locally (just like a [validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/) would)
   - takes input from: `value`
   - returns: None
   - side effects: should have none
   - signals problems by: raise `ValidationError`
3. `SomeField.run_validators(self, value)`

   - called for: each Field of `myform`
   - meaning: executes all [validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/) registered for `myform.somefield`
   - takes input from: `value`
   - returns: None
   - side effects: should have none
   - signals problems by: raise `ValidationError` combining all `ValidationError`s from the validators into one
4. `SomeField.clean(self, value)`

   - called for: each Field of `myform`
   - meaning: runs `to_python`, `validate`, and `run_validators`
   - takes input from: `value`
   - returns: the desired ("cleaned") value, usually the result of `to_python`
   - side effects: Django will insert the return value into `myform.cleaned_data`
   - signals problems by: not handling any `ValidationError` raised by the other operations
   - note: do not override.
5. `MyForm.clean_somefield(self)`

   - called for: each Field of `myform` with such a method
   - meaning: validate `somefield` locally
   - takes input from: `self.cleaned_data` (no longer just strings now!)
   - returns: the new or unchanged value for `somefield`
   - side effects: Django will insert the return value into `myform.cleaned_data`
   - signals problems by: raising `ValidationError`
   - note: This happens in the same loop as the `Field.clean` calls.
6. `MyForm.clean(self)`

   - called for: `myform` once
   - meaning: perform any cross-field validation
   - takes input from: `self.cleaned_data` (no longer just strings now!)
   - returns: either None or a dict that will become `cleaned_data`
   - side effects: Django will assign a dict return value to `myform.cleaned_data`
   - signals problems by: calling `self.add_error` or raising `ValidationError`.
     The latter will end up in `myform.non_field_errors()`.
   - note: Beware when accessing `cleaned_data`, as fields that did not
     validate will be missing.

## Extensions for `ModelForms`

Validation of a `ModelForm` has one more step added at the end:

7. `myform.instance.full_clean()`:
    calling validation on the respective model instance (if any).

And a `ModelForm's` `clean` method will also have
access to the model instance via this `instance` attribute.

## Customizing validation

For making `myform` validate just like you want, you therefore
have different possibilities:

- At the **`SomeField` class level**, you can override 
  `SomeField.to_python` or `SomeField.validate` (e.g. by subclassing)
- For **field-level validation at the `MyForm` class level**,
  you can implement `MyForm.clean_somefield` or
  just register a validator: 
  `somefield = SomeField(validators=[somevalidator])`.

  - That validator can be a standard one from 
    [`django.core.validators`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#built-in-validators) or a custom one.
  - BTW: You can place a validator function into your Form class;
    simply refrain from adding `self` as the first parameter.
- At the **MyForm level**, you can implement
  `MyForm.clean`.

## Triggering validation

This validation process can be triggered in various ways:

- calling `myform.full_clean()`
- calling `myform.is_valid()`
- accessing `myform.errors` etc.